# Cognito : User pool XXXX does not exist Exception When i use adminInitiateAuth

Tags: java, amazon-cognito

I'm using Cognito (Java SDK ) to authentication users .
It has no problem with signUp , confirm,resendConfirmationCode , reset password . 
But when i try using adminInitiateAuth to authenticate user . It shows [User pool XXXX does not exist ]  error message ?
I'm sure that Credentail key is true .
Could you tell me how to solve it , pls ?

Comment: same problem in eu-central-1 (Frankfurt) but from us-east-1 (Virginia) all works fine. i don't know why